# Angular passing multiple variables to directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this directive:

```
App.directive('typeahead', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'AEC',
    scope: {
        items: '=',
        prompt:'@',
        title: '@',
        subtitle:'@',
        model: '=',
        selindex: '=',
        onSelect:'&'
    },
    link:function(scope,elem,attrs){
        scope.handleSelection=function(selectedItem){
           scope.model=selectedItem;
           scope.current=0;
           scope.selected=true;        
           $timeout(function(){
               scope.onSelect();
           },200);
        };
        scope.current=0;
        scope.selected=true;
        scope.isCurrent=function(index){
           return scope.current==index;
        };
        scope.setCurrent=function(index){
           scope.current=index;
        };
    },
    templateUrl: 'templates/templateurl.html'
  }
});
```

I have this html:

```
<typeahead items="items" prompt="Start typing a US state" title="name" subtitle="id" model="name" on-select="onItemSelected()"/>
```

Directice is using this template:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model" placeholder="{{prompt}}" ng-keydown="selected=false"/><br/> 

<div class="items" ng-hide="!model.length || selected">
<div class="item" ng-repeat="item in items | filter:model  track by $index" ng-click="handleSelection(item[subtitle])" style="cursor:pointer" ng-class="{active:isCurrent($index)}" ng-mouseenter="setCurrent($index)">
    <p class="title">{{item[title]}}</p>
    <p class="subtitle">{{item[subtitle]}}</p>
</div>
```

This calls the function in the directive:

```
scope.handleSelection=function(selectedSubtitle){
```

What I try to achieve is to call:

```
handleSelection(item[title], item[subtitle])
```

And pick it up in the directive like this:

```
scope.handleSelection=function(selectedTitle, selectedSubtitle){
```

However, the selectedSubtitle in the directive remains empty. How can I pass the additional parameter to the directive?

Comment: It looks like if you use `ng-click="handleSelection(item[title], item[subtitle])"` and `scope.handleSelection = function(selectedTitle, selectedSubtitle) { ... }`, then the _title_ and the _subtitle_ should be correctly passed. Could you append the concrete code which does not work to the question?

Comment: Side note (which doesn't answer your question, but adding for discussion) - an alternative approach could be to just pass the `item` object directly and access the properties in the function.

Comment: Agree with @AlexOsborn, except that it's a "side note". This is in fact the proper way, in my mind, to handle this.